# In Java ME how do I change the direction of the stuff displayed to go right-to-left just for my MIDlet?

Tags: java-me, locale, nokia, midlet, right-to-left

My Java ME MIDlet allows its user to change the language of the Midlet.
My code handles the internationalization, and it works fine for left-to-right languages.
But when the user changes the language to Right-To-Left language, the correct strings are being displayed but the screens remain left-justified.

In other words, the phone's locale is en_US and I don't want to change it.
I just want to change my MIDlet's locale.
What's the simplest way to dynamically change all the screens of the MIDlet to right-justify their content?
I don't mind if the solution involves having the user restart the application.
I also don't mind if the solution is proprietary to Nokia phones if there is no Java ME solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using LCDUI, by default `StringItems` and so on will be given a default layout based on the phone's locale. i.e. `Item.LAYOUT_DEFAULT`, this means a phone with an `en_US` locale will display items left to right whereas a phone with an  `ar_EG` locale will display texts right to left.

It is however possible to **force** the layout to right justify texts using the `setLayout()` function:

```
StringItem myStringItem  = new StringItem("Title", "The text I want to display", Item.PLAIN);
myStringItem.setLayout(Item.LAYOUT_RIGHT);
append(myStringItem );
```

You could easily create a singleton `Settings` class, which could hold a flag with the  value to use for justification ( `Item.LAYOUT_LEFT` or `Item.LAYOUT_RIGHT`), and call it when setting the layout e.g.:

```
myStringItem.setLayout(Settings.getInstance().getJustification());
```

This could also be done in the constructor if you wish.

For low level `Graphics` the `drawString()` method can be used and the direction of the text altered, but you'll need to calculate the start point from the  top right of your text not the top left

```
  if (Settings.getInstance().getJustification() != Item.LAYOUT_RIGHT ) {
       g.drawString("Some Text", x + TEXT_MARGIN , y ,Graphics.TOP | Graphics.LEFT);
  } else {
       // Arabic rendering of menu items - getWidth() is the maximum length
       // of the line 
       g.drawString("Some Arabic Text",  x + getWidth() - TEXT_MARGIN, y ,
                            Graphics.TOP | Graphics.RIGHT);
  }
```

The simplest solution (which you have already rejected) would be to use `Item.LAYOUT_DEFAULT` throughout and alter the locale of the phone (of course), but you will still need to use an override for `drawString()` if you use low level graphics.

To check the correct justification I would enter the input locale using `System.getProperty("microedition.locale")` into a function such as this:

```
 static final String[] RIGHT_TO_LEFT = {
        "ar", // Arabic
        "az", // Azerbaijani
        "he", // Hebrew
        "jv", // Javanese
        "ks", // Kashmiri
        "ml", // Malayalam
        "ms", // Malay
        "pa", // Panjabi
        "fa", // Persian
        "ps", // Pushto
        "sd", // Sindhi
        "so", // Somali
        "tk", // Turkmen
        "ug", // Uighur
        "ur", // Urdu
        "yi" // Yiddish
    };

 public static int getJustification(String locale) {

        for (int index = 0; index < RIGHT_TO_LEFT.length; index++) {
            if (locale.indexOf(RIGHT_TO_LEFT[index]) != -1) {
                return Item.LAYOUT_RIGHT;
            }
        }
        return Item.LAYOUT_DEFAULT;
    }
```

Comment: side note. If target device supports [JSR 238](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=238 "J2ME Mobile Internationalization API") _Mobile I18N API_, there could be other options as well